# Adsense with Google App Domain?

Tags: google-workspace, google-adsense

I'm trying to login to [google.com/adsense](http://google.com/adsense) with my **Google Apps** credentials, but it says the service is not available for that domain.

I've been looking in the apps Dashboard how to activate it with no luck. I need to setup **Adsense for content** for the website with that Google Apps **domain**. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be avable now to do that because Google has just change the way thay Google App Domin works wicth means it now should support it.

Comment: mmm, so ... how to?

Comment: @benoror It works on mine so check your end again or just email Google telling them about it.

Comment: I had to enable the service in the dasboard under "Organization & users > Services". Never saw that section before.